# How to list files in a file system based on the limit : java

Tags: java, file, file-handling

How to list the files available in file system with the starting number and ending number?

like if there are `500` files in `C:\Test\` then how to list files starting from 1 to 20 like

give `start number and end number` based on this list the files available for particular file path.

i am trying this in java

I tried some thing like this and it gives me all the files available for the given path

```
public static List<String> loadAllFiles(String filesLocation) {

        //find OS
        //String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");

        //replace file path based on OS
        filesLocation = filesLocation.replaceAll("\\\\|/", "\\"+System.getProperty("file.separator"));

        List<String> pdfFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("In loadAllFiles execute start");
        }

        File directoryList = new File(filesLocation);
        File[] filesList = directoryList.listFiles();

        try {
            for (int count = 0; count < filesList.length; count++) {
                if (!filesList[count].isDirectory() && filesList[count].getName().endsWith(SPLIT_AND_SAVE_WORKING_FILE_EXTENSION.trim())) { 
                    // load only PDF  files
                    pdfFiles.add(filesList[count].getName().replace(SPLIT_AND_SAVE_WORKING_FILE_EXTENSION.trim(), ""));
                }
            }


        } catch (Exception filesException) {
            filesException.printStackTrace();
            //TODO : Log the exception
        } finally {

            if (filesList != null)
                filesList = null;

            if (directoryList != null)
                directoryList = null;
        }

        log.debug("In loadAllFiles execute end");

        return pdfFiles;
    }

I think the question is misunderstood, Say if i have 1000 files[file names can be anything] and i want to restrict getting the files name like i will give starting Number and ending number. like 1 to 20 and i want to load those 20 files alone.
```

Comment: After reading your question again. Do you want to list only the first 20 files from a list of 500? Or do you want to list the files which are starting with the numb2er 1 till 20? What about a file starting with 100?

Comment: yes, I want to list only the first 20 files from a list of 500. Thanks for understanding

Comment: I add two new examples to list the first 20 files in the directory.

Answer (score 9):

An example without external libraries using plain Java 7

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import static java.nio.file.DirectoryStream.Filter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

// list files starting with 1 till 20 "-.*"
public class FileNameFilter {

    private static final Filter<Path> fileNameFilter = new Filter<Path>() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(Path entry) throws IOException {
            if (!Files.isRegularFile(entry)) {
                return false;
            }
            return entry.getFileName().toString().matches("^([1][0-9]{0,1}|2[0]{0,1})-.*");
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String filesLocation = "resources/";

        Path path = Paths.get(filesLocation);
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path, fileNameFilter)) {
            for (Path entry : dirStream) {
                System.out.printf("%-5s: %s%n", "entry", entry.getFileName());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // add your exception handling here
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

**edit**
a Java 8 version

```
// list files starting with 1 till 20 "-.*"
public class FileNameFilter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String filesLocation = "resources/";

        try {
            Files.walk(Paths.get(filesLocation))
                    .filter(p -> p.getFileName().toString().matches("^([1][0-9]{0,1}|2[0]{0,1})-.*"))
                    .forEach(entry -> {System.out.printf("%-5s: %s%n", "entry", entry.getFileName());});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // add your exception handling here
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

**edit 2**
Examples to list the first 20 files in a directory.
**note** The order of the files is the same as you would run `ls` or `dir` in the directory.

Java 7 example

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class FileListLimiter {

private static final int MAX_FILES_TO_LIST = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String filesLocation = "resources/";

        Path path = Paths.get(filesLocation);
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path)) {
            int fileCounter = 1;
            for (Path entry : dirStream) {
                System.out.printf("%-5s %2d: %s%n", "entry", fileCounter++, entry.getFileName());
                if (fileCounter > MAX_FILES_TO_LIST) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // add your exception handling here
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Java 8 example

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class FileListLimiter {

private static final int MAX_FILES_TO_LIST = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String filesLocation = "resources/";

        try {
            Files.walk(Paths.get(filesLocation))
                    .filter(p -> p.toFile().isFile())
                    .limit(MAX_FILES_TO_LIST)
                    .forEach(entry -> {System.out.printf("%-5s: %s%n", "entry", entry.getFileName());});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // add your exception handling here
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `[1-20]` matches a `0`, `1` or `2`, not numbers 1 through 20.

Comment: @JakeCobb Thanks. Fixed the pattern and ask Anto to make his question more precise. As a file starting with 200 would also start with 20.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
final String pattern = "^[1-20].*";
final FileFilter filter = new RegexFileFilter(pattern);
final File[] files = directory.listFiles(filter);
```

Comment: NO @almas shaikh, it is giving me the zero files and i am not looking for text in the file but i have to list the files which are from 1 to 20 for example..

Comment: What are your file names? it would work for 1abc.txt, 20abc.txt etc.

Comment: I think the question is misunderstood, Say if i have 1000 files[file names can be anything] and i want to restrict getting the files name like i will give starting Number and ending number. like 1 to 20 and i want to load those 20 files alone.

Answer (score 1):

why not use this logic. its pretty straight forward and you will not need any substitution or replacement.i assume that you will be able to convert this into code very easily into Java. i have not tested the regex but you get the basic idea.

1.use scanner(or any other way) to get the input ranges for the start and the end limit.

2.create a directory listing scanning every file in the directory. use a for loop here.

3.define a regular expression to fetch only the starting data for the file .

```
      start pattern = (^[0-9]{0,2})[a-zA-Z].+[0-9]{0,2}$ use grouping in regular expression to fetch this group1
```

4.When you get the values from group1 check the file name if it starts with group1 data.

5 if this data falls in between the ranges that you want to search then create a arraylist and store the matched file in the arraylist.

6.carry on the process till end of the directory. The final arraylist would contain your files in the given ranges.

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Java 7 you can take advantage of [Files#walkFileTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor%29) . During `visitFile` you can use a regex to look for you specific file.

Something like this

```
Path start = Paths.get(filesLocation);

Final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([1]?[0-9]|[2][0])\\.pdf");

Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<>()  
{  
   @Override  
   public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path filePath, BasicFileAttributes attrs)  
      throws IOException  
   { 

    File f = filePath.toFile();
    if (pattern.matcher().matches(f.getName())) {
            System.out.println("Valid match found " + f.getName())
    }  
      return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;  
   }  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure i fully understood your question, but here is a Java 8 example that iterates over files of a directory sorted by name, starting at a given offset and limiting the results to a given size. It also allows you to include/exclude directories from results.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class DirectoryWalkerTest {

    public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException {
        final String filesLocation = "/path/to/files";

        System.out.println(getFiles(filesLocation, true, 0, 10));
        System.out.println(getFiles(filesLocation, true, 10, 10));

        System.out.println(getFiles(filesLocation, false, 0, 10));
        System.out.println(getFiles(filesLocation, false, 10, 10));
    }

    /**
     * Returns a limited list of filenames starting at the given offset.
     *
     * @param filesLocation     the directory to scan
     * @param filterDirectories should we include directories in results
     * @param offset            the starting offset
     * @param limit             the maximum number of results
     * @return a collection of file names
     */
    private static Collection<String> getFiles(final String filesLocation, final boolean filterDirectories,
            final int offset, final int limit) throws IOException {
        Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(Paths.get(filesLocation));

        if (filterDirectories) {
            stream = stream.filter(path -> !Files.isDirectory(path));
        }

        return stream
                .map(Path::toString)
                .sorted()
                .skip(offset)
                .limit(limit)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you could try this :

```
int begin = 0;
int limit = 10;
for (int count = 0; count < filesList.length; count++)
{
    if (!filesList[count].isDirectory() && filesList[count].getName().endsWith(SPLIT_AND_SAVE_WORKING_FILE_EXTENSION.trim()))
    {
        // moving to begin index, only if the file is not a directory and is matching your criteria, whatever it is
        if (count < begin) continue;

        // load only PDF  files
        pdfFiles.add(filesList[count].getName().replace(SPLIT_AND_SAVE_WORKING_FILE_EXTENSION.trim(), ""));
    }

    // Stopping when limit is reached
    if (pdfFiles.size() == limit) break;
}
```

It will move to `begin` index and get `limit` items, based on your criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with it and came up with something that works for me. Perhaps you can find the parts you need. If you don't want the full path, just remove the getCanonicalPath().

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FilenameFilter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class GetFirst_20_pdf_files {

        // Creating an empty array list with 10 entries (the default)
        ArrayList<String> pdfFiles = new ArrayList<String>();

        public ArrayList<String> myList() {
            // here you can get start and end from user
            int start = 2;
            int end   = 4;
            // and set the directory
            String filesLocation = ".";

            File directoryList = new File(filesLocation); 
            File[] files = directoryList.listFiles();
            int count = 0;
            for (File file : files) {
                // don't want directories
                if (file.isDirectory()) { continue; }
                // want ".pdf" files only
                if (!file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")) { continue; }
                // only want between start and end
                count++;
                if (count >= start && count <= end) {
                try {
                     pdfFiles.add(file.getCanonicalPath());
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     System.out.println(e);
                 }

                 if (count >= end) { return pdfFiles; }
                }
            }
            return pdfFiles;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            GetFirst_20_pdf_files L = new GetFirst_20_pdf_files();
            ArrayList<String> aList = L.myList();

            for (String p : aList) {
                System.out.println(p);
            }
        }
    }
```